# Angular6 not prepopulating data via API Call

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two components in my angular 6 application.
create-user.component
manage-user.component

Manage-user.component has a table which shows all the user exist in my database. There is a button to edit the user-info.

On click of edit button, I want to open the view of create-user.html from create-user.component and pre-populate data of user in the form.

Below Is my code for typeScript file:

**create-user.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from './users';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class CreateUsersComponent implements OnInit {

    user: User = new User();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
        console.log("constructor call");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Init function called");
    }

    public onEdit(userObj){
        this.router.navigate(['/user'])
        this.user =userObj;
        console.log("Value set in user property of component")
    }

    save(){
        let url = "/users";
        console.log(this.user);

        this.http.post(url, this.user)
            .subscribe((response)=> {
                console.log("saved");
            });
    }

}
```

**manage-user.component**

```
import { User } from '../users/user';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CreateUsersComponent } from "../users/createUser.component";
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  providers:[ CreateUsersComponent ],
  selector: 'manage-users',
  templateUrl: './manage-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-users.component.css']
})
export class ManageUsersComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    items: any;
    dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>();
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'age', 'address', 'action'];

    applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
        if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
            this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
        }
    }

    getAllUsers(){
        let url = "/users"
        this.http.get(url)
            .subscribe((response)=> {
                console.log(response);
                this.items = response;
                this.dataSource.data = this.items;
            });
    }

    edit(userObj){
      // Calling onEdit function of CreateUsersComponent passing the userObj
      this.userComponent.onEdit(userObj);
    }

    constructor(private userComponent: CreateUsersComponent, private http: HttpClient) { 
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.getAllUsers();
    }

}
```

The problem I am facing here is that I am not able to pre-populate the data.
I am able to see the log "Value set in user property of component"..
But the data is not filled properly. I don;t want to use ngOnInit to populate the data. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: I'd use a service to store the user object on the edit click. Get the user object from the service in the constructor of the `CreateUserComponent`. Why do you don't want to use `ngOnInit`?

Comment: The best way to do this is by using a service. As you changing the route you need to get the data from the service and prepopulate it in your create user component.

Comment: seems like its refers to same object instance. Use this.user = Object.assign({}, userObj);

Comment: @Emaro As I am doing some other operation in ngOnInit, and ngOnInit will run each time the view is loaded. I don't want to run the edit functionality on normal create flow.

Comment: Okay. However if you get the selected user (to edit) from the service, the service can return null or a new user object to provide the normal create flow.

Comment: @ShwetankTripathi what i would suggest in this case is that you have two different routes `edit-user/:id` and `create-user` now you can check if id id present then you can make an api call or get the same user from service using the id. And when the id is not there you can just initialize an empty user object. hope this helps